# upgrading yii2 advanced from 2.0.6 to 2.0.7 does not work

Tags: php, yii2

In my project directory I first executed the following two commands

```
php C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar self-update

php C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"
```

But executing the command

```
composer require yiisoft/yii2 2.0.5
yields:

Your version of PHP, 5.4.7, is affected by CVE-2013-6420 and cannot safely perform certificate validation, we strongly suggest you upgrade.
You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.



 Problem 1
    - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 2.0.7 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.7].

    - Conclusion: remove bower-asset/jquery.inputmask 3.1.63
    - Conclusion: don't install bower-asset/jquery.inputmask 3.1.63
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.7 requires bower-asset/jquery.inputmask ~3.2.2 -> satisfiable by bower-asset/jquery.inputmask[3.2.7, 3.2.6, 3.2.5, 3.2.4, 3.2.3, 3.2.2].
    - Can only install one of: bower-asset/jquery.inputmask[3.1.63, 3.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: bower-asset/jquery.inputmask[3.1.63, 3.2.6].
    - Can only install one of: bower-asset/jquery.inputmask[3.1.63, 3.2.5].
    - Can only install one of: bower-asset/jquery.inputmask[3.1.63, 3.2.4].
    - Can only install one of: bower-asset/jquery.inputmask[3.1.63, 3.2.3].
    - Can only install one of: bower-asset/jquery.inputmask[3.1.63, 3.2.2].
    - Installation request for bower-asset/jquery.inputmask (locked at 3.1.63) -> satisfiable by bower-asset/jquery.inputmask[3.1.63].



Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Any help?

Comment: pls run this command again: `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"` and share the error

Comment: Did it before and error is exactly same as in my post

Comment: Or go into your project directory using terminal and run this command: `composer update`

Comment: By the way my OS is windows 10

Comment: ran composer update with result: noting to update.  you are already using composer version 1.1.0 (stable channel)

Comment: okay just go into your www directory and create new project: `composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced yii2-app`

Comment: And then? Pls I do not understand aim of that command (composer create-project...)

Comment: It will create project and download all dependencies

Comment: Are you able to create new project?

Comment: ok, project yii2-app has been created in my www directory. Now what next pls?

Comment: go into yii2-app using cmd and run `composer update`

Comment: c:\xampp\htdocs\yii2-app>composer update
Your version of PHP, 5.4.7, is affected by CVE-2013-6420 and cannot safely perform certificate validation, we strongly suggest you upgrade.
You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files

Comment: It seems composer is working fine

Comment: So I  think problem is with yii2 package 2.0.7

Comment: pls check: [Yii2 Upgrade](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/UPGRADE.md)

Comment: I've checked it. My server configuration satisfies the minimum requirements. Rest of instructions there concern php code + have nothing to do with upgrading as such or I am mistaking?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade from Yii 2.0.6 to Yii 2.0.7, Pls visit [this link](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/UPGRADE.md)

Added new requirement: ICU Data version >= 49.1. Please, ensure that your environment has ICU data installed and up to date to prevent unexpected behavior or crashes. This may not be the case on older systems e.g. running Debian Wheezy.

Comment: I've downloaded zip file of ICU 57.1 and extracted it, but I've no idea as about where to put its folders bin, include and lib in my windows 10 system. Windows installer was not available. Any help?

Comment: in my folder c:\xampp\php\ there are  many icu dll of icu vers 46. Should I just delete them and replace them with new ones? My system uses php vers 5.4.7 or should I better upgrade php? Thx

Comment: you can update your php are reinstall wamp if you are using wamp.